# EclipseLink cannot find entity in OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

I have a very simple case with eclipse link which I have reproduced below. If I can get the below example working, then I can easily apply it to the actual case in question. Problem is, I can't!

There are two classes - `Parent` and `Child`. Both have a `String` id, and the `Parent` contains a list of `Child` objects in the field `children`. The `List` of children has the attributed `@OneToMany`, and both classes have the `@Entity` attribute. I am running everything through Eclipse as a Maven project, with the `persistence.xml` stored in `src\main\resources\META_INF\persistence.xml`. No other jars are referenced.

When I call `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` I get the following exception. It seems to think `Child` is not an entity!

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1a8e3115
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [Parent] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class com.test.Parent] uses a non-entity [class com.test.Child] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field children].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at com.test.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [Parent] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class com.test.Parent] uses a non-entity [class com.test.Child] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field children].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1950)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1941)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:96)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [Parent] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class com.test.Parent] uses a non-entity [class com.test.Child] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field children].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:230)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class com.test.Parent] uses a non-entity [class com.test.Child] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field children].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.nonEntityTargetInRelationship(ValidationException.java:1378)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.RelationshipAccessor.getReferenceDescriptor(RelationshipAccessor.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.RelationshipAccessor.processJoinTable(RelationshipAccessor.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.OneToManyAccessor.processManyToManyMapping(OneToManyAccessor.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.OneToManyAccessor.process(OneToManyAccessor.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1578)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1831)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1865)
    ... 5 more
```

I've tried so many things around this and I really have no idea what to try next. I assume I'm doing something horribly wrong, but google has finally exauhsted itself. Any help much appreciated :)

All relevant files to reproduce are below:

Parent:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private String      id;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Child> children;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

Child:

```
package com.test;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.

    <persistence-unit name="Parent">    
        <class>com.test.Parent</class>      
        <properties>        
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>      
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.read-connections.min" value="1" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.write-connections.min" value="1" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" />         
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
            <!-- Logging -->
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false" />                                
        </properties>       
    </persistence-unit> 

    <persistence-unit name="Child"> 
        <class>com.test.Child</class>       
        <properties>        
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>      
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.read-connections.min" value="1" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.write-connections.min" value="1" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" />         
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
            <!-- Logging -->
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false" />                                
        </properties>       
    </persistence-unit> 


</persistence>
```

Main class (for testing):

```
package com.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Main {
    private static final String KEY_PERSISTENCE_URL  = "javax.persistence.jdbc.url";
    private static final String KEY_PERSISTENCE_USER = "javax.persistence.jdbc.user";
    private static final String KEY_PERSISTENCE_PASS = "javax.persistence.jdbc.password";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(KEY_PERSISTENCE_URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reporting");
        properties.put(KEY_PERSISTENCE_USER, "root");
        properties.put(KEY_PERSISTENCE_PASS, "p4ssw0rd");
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Parent.class.getSimpleName(), properties);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The persistence unit being used only contains a single entity, and so has no knowledge of how to persist your referenced non-entity child class.  Child is an entity in another persistence unit, but it is just a java object to the parent PU.  The two units should be combined into one that includes all dependent entities

Comment: I had no idea multiple classes should be contained in the same persistence unit, so this looks like what I'm missing out (will have to wait until tomorrow to test, could be wrong). If a `Child` objects were contained in `Parent` _and_ `School` objects (for example), could the class be present in two separate persistence units? (assuming I would want two separate 'parent' and 'school' units in the first place).

Comment: Your entity can be in as many persistence units as needed.  It is just a java class.  The persistence unit is the storage mechanism.  I don't see why you would have parent and school separated out unless you had them in different databases, and both database instances had their own child representation allowing you to reuse the child class.

Comment: This worked - I knew I was missing something fundamental, so thankyou.